# Why is this where().first_or_create generating incorrect SQL in RSpec only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rspec

I'm seeing a case where `Action.where(:name => "fred").first_or_create` is generating incorrect SQL when run under RSpec, but performs correctly in the console.  I'm baffled.

Here's the model.  The underlying `actions` table has one field, a string named `name`:

```
# file: app/models/action.rb
class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.internalize(name)
    self.where(:name => name).first_or_create
  end
end
```

Here's the rspec test:

```
# file: spec/models/action_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe Action do
  describe 'intern' do
    it 'should create a new name' do  # works
      lambda { Action.internalize("fred") }.should change { Action.count }.by(1)
    end
    it 'should not create duplicate names' do  # fails
      Action.internalize(:name => "fred")
      lambda { Action.internalize("fred") }.should_not change { Action.count }
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the failure:

```
1) Action intern should not create duplicate names
   Failure/Error: Action.internalize(:name => "fred")
   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
     PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "name"
     LINE 1: SELECT  "actions".* FROM "actions"  WHERE "name"."name" = 'f...
     : SELECT  "actions".* FROM "actions"  WHERE "name"."name" = 'fred' LIMIT 1
   # ./app/models/action.rb:4:in `internalize'
   # ./spec/models/action_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It appears that when the record exists, `Action.where(:name => "fred").first_or_create` is generating the SQL

```
SELECT "actions".* FROM "actions" WHERE "name"."name" = 'fred' LIMIT 1
```

... which is wrong -- it's looking for a table named "name".

What's odd is that typing the exact same thing into the console performs properly.  And yes,  I remembered (this time) to type `rake db:test:prepare` before running my RSpec tests.  I'm running

```
Ruby version              1.9.3 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0)
Rails version             3.2.1
RSpec                     2.9.0
```

What the heck is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Action.internalize(:name => "fred")` is generating where clause:

```
where(:name => {:name => "fred"})
```

that mean, you have associated table `name`, that has column `name` with value `fred`

Comment: It means that the fact that it works on the Rails console is a lucky coincidence.

Comment: @Mik: Please explain?  As far as I can tell, `Action.internalize(:name => "fred")` generates the where clause `Action.where(:name => "fred")`, no?  [See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions].  Where do you get the nested hash?

Comment: @Mik: OOHHHHH!  Yep, that was a really stupid typo on my part.  The call to Action.internalize(:name => "fred") should simply be Action.internalize("fred").  You don't know how many times I stared at that bit of code and completely missed it.

Comment: BTW, I seriously considered deleting this entire question because it was such an embarrassing mistake on my part.  But maybe it will help someone else!